# time complexity for a loop with for x+= 2 and h *= n increment

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

```
for ... {
    for (int x = 0; x < n; x+=2 {
        for ( int h = 1; h < n; h *= n ) {
        \\some constant operation
        }
    }
}
```

I feel like the complexity for the first loop is n-2 and for the second for loop the complexity is log_{n}(n) for the last loop, however wouldn't that just be 1?

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Constant factors are ignored, the overall complexity is ***O(n log n)***

Comment: @JimGarrison, however, this doesn't confirm whether my assumptions on what the time complexities for each loop are correct or not! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
for ... {
    for (int x = 0; x < n; x+=2 {
        for ( int h = 1; h < n; h *= n ) {
            //some constant operation
        }
    }
}
```

I will note the first loop as running *k* iterations, since you don't specify.
The next loop runs ceil(*n* / 2) times (e.g. if n = 5, loops with x=0,2,4). You can understand this as the loop processing (essentially) every other element, so it skips half of them.
The next loop runs **once**. After the first iteration, the increment statement immediately causes the condition of the loop to evaluate to false.

The runtime of this snippet is thus O(*kn*).

Comment: Thank you so much! why does the second for loop have a running time of n/2 and what does k represent?